# P-value in XGBresressor

Tags: python, regression, probability, xgboost, xgbregressor

How to compute the p-value in XGBregressor and SVR?
The suggested method is Bonferroni's method. I know adjusted p-value= min{1, raw p-value * the number of features}. In fact, I do not know how to compute the p-value.

Comment: Before understanding **adjusted** p-values, you need to be at ease with the concept of p-value. adjusted p-val is just a way to make it more accurate, taking into account the fact that many statistical tests are performed.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do this (this is an example):

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_regression
import xgboost as xgb

california_housing = fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True)

X, y = california_housing.data, california_housing.target
xgb_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor()
xgb_reg.fit(X, y)

f_vals, p_vals = f_regression(X, y)

feat_idx = 0

raw_p_val = p_vals[feat_idx]
num_features = X.shape[1]

adj_p_val = min(1, raw_p_val * num_features)

print("Raw p-value:", raw_p_val)
print("Adjusted p-value:", adj_p_val)
```

which givs

```
Raw p-value: 0.0
Adjusted p-value: 0.0
```

Comment: Based on the code, It sounds that the Raw p-value and Raw p-value do not depend on XGBregressor. Is it right? In fact, I want to compare the efficiency of SVR and XGBreserror by the p-value.

Comment: The ```raw p-value``` and ```adjusted p-value``` are calculated based on the ```F-value``` and the number of features, which are computed using the ```f_regression function```. The f_regression function does not depend on any specific estimator like XGBRegressor .